# Split colon-separated string in a column into several columns in R

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c('0/1:60,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28', '0/1:58,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30', '0/1:25,2:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16'))

data

                                    col1
1 0/1:60,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28
2 0/1:58,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30
3   0/1:25,2:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16
```

I want to extract the number between the first and second colons, namely `60,4`, `58,4`, `25,2`, and split it into different columns.

```
  col1 col2
1   60    4
2   58    4
3   25    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We extract the substring with `sub`, and use `read.csv` to create two new columns

```
read.csv(text = sub("^[^:]+:(\\d+,\\d+):.*", "\\1", data$col1), 
      header = FALSE, col.names = c('col1', 'col2'))
```

-output

```
#   col1 col2
#1   60    4
#2   58    4
#3   25    2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use tidyr's `extract`:

```
tidyr::extract(data, col1, c("col1", "col2"), "^.*?(\\d+),(\\d+)")
  col1 col2
1   60    4
2   58    4
3   25    2
```